# C# - Zoom GeckoWebBrowser (GeckoFX 45) like in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, zooming, geckofx

I want to zoom GeckoWebBrowser like in Mozilla Firefox (on image) using C# or JavaScript 
[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this feature:

`this.BrowserForThisInstance.GetDocShellAttribute().SetZoomAttribute(34);`

[image]

Regards